I'm trying to set up an allow list in intune for URLAllowList with multiple URL's and some with wild cards
I am using ["*"] to block everything using Managed Devices enrollment type and Block access to a list of URLs "URLBlocklist" but want to whitelist some urls with wildcards as there are pages of forms to create and sign into accounts.
I've created a seperate profile to play around with to get it to work so only has allow
Device enrollment type Managed devices
Platform Android Enterprise
Profile Type Fully Managed, Dedicated, and Corporate-Owned Work Profile Only
Targeted app Microsoft Edge: AI browser
I currently have this JSON below at the moment and i can get to www.archivescard.com and edge://policy
{
"kind": "androidenterprise#managedConfiguration",
"productId": "app:com.microsoft.emmx",
"managedProperty": [
{
"key": "URLAllowlist",
"valueStringArray": [
"https://www.archivescard.com/",
"https://archivescard.com/*",
"edge://policy"
]
}
]
}
looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/manage-microsoft-edge#url-formats-for-allowed-and-blocked-site-list i should be able to use wildcards although becasue i'm using ValueStringArray I don't know if it will have the same behavour.
When i try and enter it in like URL1|URL2|URL3 using a string it is blocked even if i just put the addresses in without wildcards but if i put a signle url it works but not with wildcards.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Intune/comments/1bzroml/comment/kyrsuti/ is what I found to get the allow multiple addresses to work.

Could you please describe the problem more clearly? Based on my understanding, you are trying to find a way to include multiple URLs with wildcards but failed, right? Does the solution you have found in reddit also work for wildcards?

No the way i found only works with a single page

I don't think you are using the wildcard properly, and there's no need for you to use wildcard in this case. I guess you want to allow the subdomains, but the right way to express "Match archivescard.com and its subdomains" is just archivescard.com. The wildcard is not needed. You should be able to include multiple URLs by removing those wildcards.
You may find reference of the URL format here.

Thank you that makes sense. I took "Ensure that you prefix all URLs with http:// or https:// when entering them into the list." to include www. as well
